# What is good javascript ajax library for a custom library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A little explanation: I'm building a library to handle some back and forth with our CMS and have decided to open source it. Right now I have a dependency on jQuery 1.5 for it's AJAX method, specifically the recently added [statusCode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) object. This is the only depency, and I'm not expecting others.

Are there any lightweight AJAX only libraries out there capable of this functionality? I'd rather not include all of jQuery if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [`ender`](https://github.com/ender-js/Ender). Which allows you to include *only* what you want. I believe the ajax library included is very small.

You should avoid [Single points of failure](http://happyworm.com/blog/2011/03/07/p2p-web-apps-brace-yourselves-everything-is-about-to-change/) like having other services host code for you.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It's ok. Don't mind the "jQuery is the only tool I have so hammer away!" crowd.

Answer (score 3):

Just get those codes:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/intro.js
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/ajax (get the files depending on what methods you use)
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/outro.js

And gather them in  a single file. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not call jQuery directly from google. Since most users use google, many will already have jQuery cached and will not have the need to reload jQuery when accessing your site.

```
<script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check out this blog `3 reasons why you should let google host your jQuery`. 
http://encosia.com/2008/12/10/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Comment: You initialize the all components of jQuery.

Comment: And take a look at what they do to include jQuery in http://html5boilerplate.com/ : They get it from the CDN and if there's a problem, they get the local one. You should do that too.

Comment: @xavierm02 i think you're missing the point, start by reading the blog to better understand how this works.

Comment: I'm trying to remove jQuery dependencies from my library so that it will be easier to integrate with any framework.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Mochikit](http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/index.html), but it does more that just AJAX, but has a better async handling method using the Deferred object. It is smaller than Jquery.